# How to get average rate for restaurant from menus in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how to get the average rate for a restaurant ?
without do loop on query

restaurant has many menu. 
menu has many rate.

in model restaurant

```
public function menus()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Menu', 'fk_restaurant');
}
```

in model menu

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rate', 'fk_service');
}
```

code in RestaurantController

```
$mostRatedRestaurants = Restaurant::where('status', 1)->with('menus')->get();
```

before add question I am searching but when try any solution get error 
"Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on int"

thanks, Advanced.

Comment: i am not familiar with the phrase 'menu has many rate.' - do you mean price?

Comment: the line of code that you have posted at the end works? if yes, what you mean with ''without using loops''? you mean explicitly using loops (writing them on the script) or you mean to calculate it on the Database? because if it's the first case, in the foreach you are like printing them, you can use the collection avg method to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done solve It thanks, guys.

I am create method

```
    public function getAvgRate($mostRatedRestaurants){
        foreach ($mostRatedRestaurants as $mostRatedRestaurant){
            $ratedRestaurant = 0;
            $countMenuHasRate = 0;
            $avgRateRestaurant = 0;
            foreach($mostRatedRestaurant->menus as $menu){
                // عدد تقييمات الوجبة
                $countReviewForMenu = count($menu->reviews);
                $rate = 0;
                foreach($menu->reviews as $reviews){
                    $rate += $reviews->rate;
                }
                if(count($menu->reviews) !== 0){
                    $rateForMenu = round($rate/$countReviewForMenu); // rate Menu;
                    $countMenuHasRate += 1;
                    $ratedRestaurant += $rateForMenu;
                }
            }
            if($ratedRestaurant !== 0) {
                $avgRateRestaurant = round($ratedRestaurant / $countMenuHasRate);
            }
            $mostRatedRestaurant['rate'] = $avgRateRestaurant ?? 0;
        }
        return $mostRatedRestaurants;
    } // End Method getAvgRate
```

and inside mehtod index

```
$mostRatedRestaurants = Restaurant::where('status', 1)->with('profileImage', 'menus')->get();
$mostRatedRestaurants = $this->getAvgRate($mostRatedRestaurants); // Add Rate
$mostRatedRestaurants = $mostRatedRestaurants->sortByDesc('rate')->take('9'); // Sort Rate

return view('user.content.restaurant.index', compact('mostRatedRestaurants'));
```

in blade For echo Rate

```
@php
    $rate = 5 - $mostRatedRestaurant->rate;
@endphp
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $rate; $i++)
    <li class="far fa-star text-secondary float-left text-left"></li>
@endfor

@php 
  $rate = $mostRatedRestaurant->rate;
@endphp
@for ($i = 1; $i <= $rate; $i++)
    <li class="fa fa-star"></li>
@endfor
```

you can improve code
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you test this :

```
$mostRatedRestaurants = Restaurant::App\Menu::find(1);

$mostRatedRestaurants->where('status', 1)->get();
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for reply. 

done solve it and done added solution in comment.